# AdMob anuncios tardan en cargar

Tags: flutter, dart, admob

Buen día, lance mi aplicación a la Playstore y tengo un problema con los anuncios. Resulta que cuando un usuario la instala por primera vez, los anuncios tardan en cargar alrededor de 2 horas, pero cuando ya la ha instalado cargan de inmediato. Esto es un problema para mi ya que quiero invertir en publicidad pero perdería todos esos anuncios de la primera ronda. Mi pregunta es, esto será siempre así? Es un error mio? es temporal? de antemano muchas gracias. No tengo mucha experiencia con ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un procedimiento normal para las cuentas de AdMob. Despues de unos dias todo regresa a la normalidad.